# Sharepoint Online search result is different on filename search with and without asterisk wild character

Tags: sharepoint

I have two files, BTWaste.RN_SpecSheet.pdf and BTWasteCI.RN_SpecSheet.pdf, which are on same library, same folder and upload at the same time.  I use "filename: btwaste" and "filename: btwaste*" to search.  I expect result are the same for both search. Why only one file on search result for "filename: btwaste" searching?

I remove dot on file name, BTWasteRN_SpecSheet.pdf and BTWasteCIRN_SpecSheet.pdf, result is still the same.

[image: With astrisk]

[image: Without astrisk]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Please ask on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's how KQL query works in SharePoint:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

> When you use words in a free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint
> returns results based on exact matches of your words with the terms
> stored in the full-text index. You can use just a part of a word, from
> the beginning of the word, by using the wildcard operator (*) to
> enable prefix matching. In prefix matching, Search in SharePoint
> matches results with terms that contain the word followed by zero or
> more characters.